# Does the RedQueryBuilder provide a DatePicker when entering a value

Tags: redquerybuilder

The [RedQueryBuilder](http://redquerybuilder.appspot.com/) demo does not show an example of entering a query criteria against a date field.

Is it possible to specify a date value with a DatePicker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You use the editor type "DATE"... Not very sophisticated at the moment. Could do with a sensible "BETWEEN" editor. Please raise an issue on https://github.com/salk31/RedQueryBuilder/issues if you need something like that.